# how to project by a value as a property in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this Object:

```json
{
    "_id":"1",
    "a":"b",
    "b":"wanted value"
},
{
    "_id":"2",
    "a":"c",
    "c":"wanted value 2"
}
```

how can i get the value of a and make it the property with which i project to get "wanted value"/"wanted value 2" ?

wanted output:

```
{
    "_id":"1",
    "b":"wanted value"
},
{
    "_id":"2",
    "c":"wanted value 2"
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your expected output?

Comment: out put:{b:"wanted value"},{c:"wanted value 2"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$objectToArray` to convert the root document into an array of k-v tuples then use `$reduce` to process the array.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "arr": {
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "v": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$arr",
          "initialValue": null,
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.k",
                  "a"
                ]
              },
              "then": "$$this.v",
              "else": "$$value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "arr": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$arr",
          "as": "tuple",
          "cond": {
            $eq: [
              "$$tuple.k",
              "$v"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "result": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$arr"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$result"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q3dqCexQCSx) for your reference.

Comment: Only that i need the property to be b and c not in result

Comment: @SeekingKnowledge updated the solution. The idea is the same, using `$objectToArray` to process the dynamic field names. Just some more cosmetics with `$arrayToObject` and `$replaceRoot` at the later stages.